# How do I create an org.xml.sax.InputSource from a String?

Tags: java, xml

I am following a guide, and it gives me the following code:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/xml/file.xml"))));
```

What I would like to know, is how I can still create an `org.xml.sax.InputSource`, but instead of reading the content of a file, use a `String` variable that I already have.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use a `StringReader` instead of a `FileInputStream`.

See the documentation for [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)

example:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( new StringReader( myString ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

`InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(string));` if it is `org.xml.sax.InputSource`.